# Returning from http lambda endpoint for longer than 30s

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, apache-camel-aws-kinesis

I need to return a lot of data from a lambda over http. It's a slow query for a lot of data and will easily exceed the 30s limit. It's not an option to introduce paging but it's okay to be a long slow request. It needs to be a simple `GET` endpoint. These requirements are imposed by a third party.

Would it be possible to return a stream of some sort e.g. s3 stream or kinesis stream?

Comment: What do you mean by a lot of data?

Comment: can't you use a presigned S3 url? The data is stored into S3 and streamed to the end user. If the third party follows an url redirection, you can just return a 302 status code with the S3 presigned url as location.

Comment: yeah that would normally work! The thing is the file needs to be generated on the fly and ideally I don't want to return any redirect status codes.

Comment: You have several issues with Lambda: maximum output (6MB), timeout (APIGW). The invocation type of Lambda (and APIGW) does not allow streaming.